# Random Selection in a Column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've modified a code to select a data randomly from A Column cells. The problem I'm facing is, I'm only able to get the data from A1. and rest of the data are not showing. Where did I go wrong?

```
function getData () {
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var Avals = SS.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var numberOfValues = Avals.filter(String).length;
var data = SS.getRange(1,1,numberOfValues).getValues();

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
  { 
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(data[i].length)); //method of randomization
    var element = data[i][j];


return element;

logger.log(element);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- `getValues()` returns a 2D array. In your case you have a single column, therefore `data` has the format of: `[[a1],[a2],[a3],..]]`. `data[i]` will give you a single element of this array. For example `data[0]` is `[a1]` and as you can understand `[a1].length` is equal to `1` regardles of the chosen index. In other words, `data[i].length` is `1` for every `i` and therefore you are always getting the first element.
- It is also worth mentioning that you have a `return` statement inside the `for` loop and therefore `i` gets only the first value `0` since the function is terminated when reaches the `return` statement. You don't need a for loop if you want to get a single random element from the column.

Since `data[i].length` is equal to `1`  this expression `Math.random()*(data[i].length)` returns a number between `0` and `1` but **less** than `1`. Therefore `Math.floor(Math.random()*(data[i].length))` always returns `0` and as a result `data[0][0]` is equal to the value of the first cell `A1`.

- Please notice that `logger.log(element)` is wrong. It should be `Logger.log(element);` but you are not getting any error since `return` is before that line and the function never reaches that line.
- Finally, I used `flat()` to convert the 2D array to 1D and therefore `data.length` returns the correct length of the array but also you can now index it with one variable.

---

### Solution:

```
function getData () {
const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh = SS.getActiveSheet();
const Avals = sh.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
const numberOfValues = Avals.filter(String).length;
const data = sh.getRange(1,1,numberOfValues).getValues().flat();
const j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(data.length)); //method of randomization
const element = data[j];
Logger.log(element);
return element;
}
```

Comment: Booom.. it worked :) Thank you for your assistance and Thank you for giving clear insight over the code in order to understand what's happening.